# Create String from object PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I created a PHPWriter through PHPExcel and was able to write to my excel file. now after writing to my excel file i want to retrieve the value from cell C9 and display it to screen. What am i doing wrong ? . How can i display the value of C9 ! Thanks

```
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
    $objPHPExcelReader = $objReader->load('test.xlsx');
    $objPHPExcelReader->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('C9')->getValue();
    $objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
```

Comment: What's wrong? Besides the logic of calling `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('C9')->getValue();` without ever setting `$objPHPExcel`?

Comment: *damn i wrote that wrong. no my code is $objPHPExcelReader instead of $objPHPExcel.....but thats not my problem nor the question. How do you echo an object ? how to make it a string and echo it

Comment: So can you show real code?

Comment: Normally you'd do something as simple as `echo $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('C9')->getValue();` So what happens when you do that?

Comment: it tells me sheet1!F12 not the value

Comment: What do you expect to see? What does it show in MS Excel? Is it a formula? (in which case, try using `getCalculatedValue(); ` instead of `getValue()`).

Comment: You are a champ my friend :) . Thanks loads !